# Need to post JSON as an array of objects via Retrofit while dynamically adding objects

Tags: android, retrofit, pojo

I have to post a JSON Array of objects. The JSON sample is pasted below:

```
[
{
    "checklistkey": "what is your age ___ and ur bd___",
    "checklistvalue": "yes",
    "taskId": "PMTASK-cmms-01-71-1"
},
{
    "checklistkey": "how r you___? ______",
    "checklistvalue": "no",
    "taskId": "PMTASK-cmms-DE01-71-1"
}
```

]

The number of object here will be added dynamically based on the ID received in the previous request.

Now the POJO for this looks like:

```
public class CheckListAddRequest {
@SerializedName("taskId")
@Expose
private String taskId;
@SerializedName("checklistkey")
@Expose
private String checklistkey;
@SerializedName("checklistvalue")
@Expose
private String checklistvalue;

public String getTaskId() {
    return taskId;
}

public void setTaskId(String taskId) {
    this.taskId = taskId;
}

public String getChecklistkey() {
    return checklistkey;
}

public void setChecklistkey(String checklistkey) {
    this.checklistkey = checklistkey;
}

public String getChecklistvalue() {
    return checklistvalue;
}

public void setChecklistvalue(String checklistvalue) {
    this.checklistvalue = checklistvalue;
}

public CheckListAddRequest(String taskId, String checklistkey, String checklistvalue) {
    this.taskId = taskId;
    this.checklistkey = checklistkey;
    this.checklistvalue = checklistvalue;
}}
```

The Retrofit call for this is:

```
 @POST("cmms")
@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
Call<CheckListAddResponse> getCheckListAdd(@Body CheckListAddRequest checkListAddRequest,
                                           @Header("X-Auth-Token") String token,
                                           @Header("workspace") String workspace);
```

Now while added the details for creating a JSON request, I write something like:

```
CheckListAddRequest checkListAddRequest = new CheckListAddRequest(taskNumber, checkDesc, statusString);
```

Now if I have more than one object in the request, how can I send it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be an array/list  if its multiple and dynamic objects, you can easily change items add or remove from List and send

**ArrayList< CheckListAddRequest >.**

make this minor change.

```
@POST("cmms")
@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
Call<CheckListAddResponse> getCheckListAdd(@Body ArrayList<CheckListAddRequest> checkListAddRequest,
                                           @Header("X-Auth-Token") String token,
                                           @Header("workspace") String workspace);
```

now pass the value in array list or list.